# Segmentation fault in C while using pointers

Tags: c, pointers

I don't know what's happening here:

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main() 
{
    int i, j, *k, x,array[]={5,3,4,1,8,9,2,7,6,0};
    int *ptr=array;

    for(j=1;j<10;j++) {
        printf("---------iteration %d--------------\n",j);
        *k=*(ptr+j);   // the segmentation error is occurring here at this line
        printf("key=%d\n",*k);
        i=j-1;

        while( i>=0 && *k < *(ptr+i)) {
            *(ptr+i+1)=*(ptr+i);
            i--;
        }

        *(ptr+i+1) = *k;
        printf("%d\n",*(ptr+i+1));

        for( x=0;x<10;x++)
            printf("%d,",*(ptr+x));

        printf("\n");
    }

    for( i=0;i<10;i++)
        printf("%d,",*ptr++);

    printf("\n");
}
```

The error is occurring right after the `printf` statement in the `for` loop and when I remove the `*` from the both the sides it works but the answer is wrong.

This is an insertion sort using pointers in C.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.  Do not use `void main()` in code posted here unless you like being shouted at for doing so.  And please, please, please indent your code, 4 spaces per level (no tabs).

Comment: My apologies for that. could you please direct me to an article or could you tell me about the rules of formatting while writing a code.

Comment: And also, I have come across few variables and structures and function names that start with __ (two under scores) and also ones ending with ' _in ' and ' _t ' !
could you explain them to me.

Comment: Names that start with two underscores (or an underscore and a capital letter) are 'reserved for the implementation' for any use.  Do not create such names yourself, and only use those documented, such as `__FILE__` or `__func__`.  Other names that start with an underscore are also mostly reserved to the implementation for a more restricted set of uses; again, stay clear.  (C Standard, §7.1.3 Reserved Identifiers.) Types ending in `_t` are reserved to the implementation by POSIX.  Again, tread with caution. I've not seen `_in` as a pervasive suffix; I'm not aware of any proscription on them.

Comment: As for C style guidelines, a Google search will uncover many.  There are a few major styles. My observation about tabs and spaces is pragmatic rather than dogmatic. SO more or less treats tabs as 4 spaces, but code that was formatted under other settings doesn't look good. Indentation is crucial to easy understanding of code.  Vim has a quick, effective system for indenting automatically, using `=%` when you are on a curly bracket `{` or `}`. Note that when editing a question or answer, the `{}` button indents or outdents the selection by 4 spaces. A character in columns 1-4 forces an indens.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem is, as you said, right after `printf()`:

```
*k=*(ptr+j)
```

I didn't get as far as looking at the right side.  The left side definitely has a problem:  the pointer is not initialized, so writing to that address will almost certainly cause trouble.

The right side has a memory access too, but, after inspection it looks like it might be okay.

Comment: I wonder what the point of `*k` is ... looks like `k` alone would suffice? (As all access to indirect or "dereferenced" or whatever the correct term is ^^)

Comment: *k is the rvalue of the pointer and if use only k then the rvalue of the pointer (ptr+j) will get placed into the pointer but not the address.

Answer (score 2):

You have declared `k` as a pointer but haven't given it any memory to point to, so there's no telling what will happen when you write to it. Give it some memory to write to with `k = malloc(sizeof array)`.

Comment: But why does it have to be initialized ?
It can have any garbage value right like integers and characters etc. ? all i am doing is assigning it to an existing value inside a variable.

Comment: @hunterr986: Because if a pointer isn't initialized, you are accessing a quasi-random memory location, which typically is not a valid memory location, which is what leads to a segmentation fault.  Or it might be a null pointer; that too is not valid and typically leads to a segmentation fault.  If you don't know that a pointer is valid, it is not safe to use it!  **And** No, you are not assigning to the pointer; you are assigning to what the (uninitialized) pointer points at. To assign to the pointer use: `k = ptr + j;` which gives you a valid pointer, assuming `ptr` and `j` are under control.

Comment: @hunterr986 you are partly correct, in that the thing-you-are-assigning-to can have any garbage value before the assignment, but the thing-you-are-assigning-to here is `*k`, and if `k` has a garbage value then `*k` is a meaningless (and invalid) concept, rather than a place you can usefully store something.

Comment: @hunterr986 If you just used `k = x`, `k` wouldn't have to be initialized because, as I think you're trying to say, it's just going to be overwritten with the right data anyway. But in the code you have, you're not assigning the value to `k`, you're assigning the value to a point in memory, using `k` as the address at which the memory is located. Since you haven't told `k` the address it should point to, it could point you anywhere, which most likely won't be where you actually want to write the value.

Answer (score 1):

As stated by the others, part of your problem is that you are using an unitialized pointer to store a value.  After reading your code, it appears that you are using *k simply to store an integer value and nothing else; therefore you don't need to have a pointer and using an ordinary int value should suffice:

```
int i, j, k, x,array[]={5,3,4,1,8,9,2,7,6,0}; 
int *ptr=array; 

for(j=1;j<10;j++) { 
    printf("---------iteration %d--------------\n",j); 
    k=*(ptr+j);   // the segmentation error is occurring here at this line 
    printf("key=%d\n",k); 
    i=j-1; 

    while( i>=0 && k < *(ptr+i)) { 
        *(ptr+i+1)=*(ptr+i); 
        i--; 
    } 

    *(ptr+i+1) = k;
}
```

Furthermore, while *(ptr+i) represents the same thing as ptr[i], the usual C/C++ convention would be to use the later form.

Comment: i am trying to learn pointers so i am programming mostly using pointers.

Comment: Then you should learn how to initialise pointer before accesssing its memory location: [code] int *k, km; k = &km; [/code]  With km, you reserve on the stack the memory for an int and after that, you make k to point toward the address of this reserved memory. With this, you'll be able to use *k without any corruption problem.

Answer (score 0):

The code below is close to your original, with the bug fixed, and a couple of tweaks for good measure.  The main fix is replacing `*k` with `key` (which is pretty much what @pst and @SylvainL have already said.)

The reason, from the algorithm standpoint, is you need somewhere outside of `array` to hold the value being moved while the other `array` elements are shifted.  Otherwise you end up overwriting `array` elements, which I suspect is what you found judging from the "*...and when I remove the `*` from the both the sides it works but the answer is wrong.*" comment.

The [Wikipedia entry on insertion sort](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Insertion_sort) has a nice animation that illustrates the point nicely:
[image] 
(image by Swfung8 [CC BY-SA License page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:Insertion-sort-example-300px.gif))

See code comments for other tweaks, as they aren't relevant to the question, just helpful pointers that you can take or leave ;-)

```
#include<stdio.h>

int main() 
{
    int array[]={5,3,4,1,8,9,2,7,6,0};

    int elm, key, i;
    int *ptr=array;

    // Calculate the number of array elements so the code will still 
    // work if the data set changes.  A good habit, rather than a necessity 
    // in this code, but it is used in two places... ;-) .

    int array_len = sizeof(array) / sizeof(int);

    for(elm=1; elm < array_len; elm++) {
        printf("---------iteration %d--------------\n",elm);
        key=(ptr+elm);
        printf("key=%d\n", key);

        // The while loop here was a for loop in disgise.

        for ( i=elm-1; i >= 0 && key < *(ptr+i); i-- ) {
            *(ptr+i+1) = *(ptr+i);
        }

        *(ptr+i+1) = key;
        printf("%d\n",*(ptr+i+1));

        // x declaration moved to here as it is only used as a loop counter

        for(int x=0; x < array_len; x++)
            printf("%d,",*(ptr+x));

        printf("\n");
    }

    for( i=0; i < 10; i++)
        printf("%d,",*ptr++);

    printf("\n");
}
```